# How can I build Docker images on Jenkins Pipeline, without changing permissions on the underlying Jenkins VM?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use Jenkins Pipeline to build, push, and deploy my Docker image.

I get this:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the 
Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

[Other questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket-at-uni) suggest `sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins`, then restart Jenkins, but I do not have access to the machine running Jenkins -- and anyway, it seems strange that Jenkins Pipeline, which is built all around Docker, cannot run a basic Docker command.

How can I build my Docker?

```
pipeline {
    agent  any
    stages {    
         stage('deploy') {
            agent {
                  docker {
                    image 'google/cloud-sdk:latest'
                    args '-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
                  }
            }
            steps {    
                 script {    
                    docker.build  "gcr.io/myporject/mydockerimage:1"
                } 
             }
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipeline definition shown is trying to execute the docker build inside a docker container (google/cloud-sdk:latest). Instead you should do the following given the jenkins user on the host has permission to execute docker commands on the host.

```
pipeline {
  agent  any
  stages {
    stage('deploy') {
      steps {    
        script {    
          docker.build  "gcr.io/myporject/mydockerimage:1"
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is nothing strange about jenkins unable to execute docker commands without proper permission when they are installed and configured separately on the machine.

Comment: What is the key difference here? Just the lack of the "agent { docker {...." block?

Comment: Yes. When you add an agent section inside a stage it will override the agent defined in the top level.

Comment: Your solution is correct  -- but I still wonder, why NOT run the build inside a Docker container. For  example, that  allows me to install build tools like kubectl and gcloud ,  and set their credentials,  without worrying about  disrupting the GCE VM  it is running in.

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to have docker installer inside a docker container.  You can probably split the stuff you are doing into multiple stages like build docker container on the host set some variables then in a different stage which can be inside a container do something with it. Also pipeline has `withCredentials` to handle credentials securely.