# Hyperledger Fabric cannot download Docker images

Tags: docker, curl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following this [tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html) of Hyperledger Fabric, and when i run the command:

```
curl -sSL'bit link here' | bash -s
```

everything is download except the docker images. I got this error:

```
 ===> List out hyperledger docker images
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/images/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

My docker version is: 18.09.7 and I am using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Seems like your issue is about user rights. Consider including your user to docker group. [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket-at-uni) links can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try to run it as sudoer.

*EDIT:*

What I mean: Something like:

```sh
sudo bash -c "curl -sSL'bit link here' | bash -s"
```

It should work, but maybe it is cleaner to follow these instructions: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user