# Bitnami Jenkins: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket

Tags: docker, jenkins, permissions, debian, bitnami

```
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
```

I'm getting this whenever I try to run Docker inside Jenkins. The machine was installed using the Bitnami Jenkins image. I have exhausted every troubleshooting option I can think of in an effort to solve what should be a simple permissions issue, but keep coming up empty.

I have attempted [all the suggestions here at this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socke). I have attempted adding `jenkins`, `bitnami`, `azureuser` and anyone else on the system that looks like they might run Docker to the `docker` group using `sudo usermod -a -G docker <user>`.

I can `sudo su - jenkins` and `docker run hello-world` without issues.

Yet, still, no matter what I do, I am reduced to this error.

`sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` does nothing.
`sudo usermod -a -G docker bitnami` does nothing.
`sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins` does nothing.
`sudo usermod -a -G docker literallyanyusericanthinkof` does nothing.
Rebooted/restarted hundreds of times now, no help.

I can run Docker in literally any other context on the machine, but Jenkins still refuses to run it. I am at my whits end getting this to work. I've configured at least two other Jenkins servers to do this before, but this one is giving me grief and I have no idea why.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Add `jenkins` user to docker group and then try.

Answer (score 2):

So I don't necessarily feel good about this, but I ran into this issue today and I got around it by changing the ownership on the docker.sock file in /var/run to jenkins:docker and now my Jenkins is working. The command I ran was

```
sudo chown jenkins:docker /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Jenkins, but for my personal account, my method was similar to @benjaminpazienza above.  I also don't feel great about it but it works.

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, Jenkins restart didn't work as well.

I found that **restarting the machine hosting the Jenkins** will fix it. Avoid giving r/w access to others by `chmod` as much as you can.