# Preparation failed: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-daemon, cicd

Trying to transform a project in gitlab to docker image. The gitlab is selfhosted. This is the error I get:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.12.0 (7a6612da)
on test -KnwQXuT
Preparing the "docker" executor
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon 
socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.25/info: dial 
unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied (docker.go:858:0s)
```

I added a runner,registered it,  created a gitlab-ci.yml with docker template which I left unmodified. As solutions I tried `chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock` before and after adding the runner but it did not work. I also added sudo before running and registering the docker runner but still no success. I found another option to add my docker user to group docker but all my users are in the docker group. The docker runner is run as a docker image. I did not know what to do...Please help. I`m am trying for about 10 days with no success... Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide you runner config

Comment: 1.  docker volume create gitlab-runner-config 2.docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v gitlab-runner-config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
    gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest 3. docker run --rm -it -v gitlab-runner-config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest register

Comment: These are the 3 steps that i took

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socke)

Answer (score 15):

1. Create docker group if not exist : `sudo groupadd docker`
2. Add user to docker group : `sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}`
3. Change docker.sock to new permission : `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`
4. Finally restart docker daemon service : `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Comment: What user ? I am root on linux

Comment: @SerCio If you root user not required any access for docker

Comment: It doesn`t work. I have given the command sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock and still receiving error. I do not know what to do...

Comment: Please don't give advice of `chmod 666` the docker.sock as this has huge security implications as this allows any user to become root

Answer (score 7):

When you use gitlab self-hosted runner, by default, it creates a user named *gitlab-runner*. You need to assign the permissions to it.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
```

this will assign the correct permissions to the gitlab-runner and should pull the docker images on that VM.