# minikube - Why The "docker" driver should not be used with root privileges

Tags: docker, minikube

When trying to start minikube with docker driver, as a root user I get:

```
$ minikube start --driver=docker
* minikube v1.16.0 on Ubuntu 18.04
* Using the docker driver based on user configuration
* The "docker" driver should not be used with root privileges.
* If you are running minikube within a VM, consider using --driver=none:
*   https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/

X Exiting due to DRV_AS_ROOT: The "docker" driver should not be used with root privileges.
```

What is the problem to use docker driver as a root user?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7903#issuecomment-619465709

Answer (score 24):

This is a question of security. In official docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface) written clearly about the risks.

As per documentation -

> Docker allows you to share a directory between the Docker host and a guest container; and it allows you to do so without limiting the access rights of the container. This means that you can start a container where the /host directory is the / directory on your host; and the container can alter your host filesystem without any restriction.

###### To solve your problem you can follow these steps:

###### Add new User

```sh
adduser newUser
usermod -aG sudo newUser
su - newUser
```

###### Login to the newly created User

```sh
su - newUser
```

###### Add User to the Docker Group

```sh
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

###### Relogin and the start minikube with this following commands

```sh
minikube start --driver=docker
```

###### Verify minikube is running

```sh
docker ps
```

Here is a github [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7903) you may have a look.

###### Updating my answer as it is causing confusion if this steps will solve the security issues

This steps will solve the error you were facing when you were trying to start minikube. But this steps won't solve the security issues because docker group grants privileges equivalent to the root user. To run docker without root privilege aka rootless mode you need to follow this [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless).

Comment: When you run those steps to add your user to the docker group, you gave that user passwordless access to the root account on the host. So I'm not sure what that solved.

Comment: This steps will solve the error @RafaelJan is facing. But this steps won't solve the security issues because docker group grants privileges equivalent to the root user. To run docker as without root privilege he needs to follow this documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

Comment: To add user to docker group , below work for me:  "sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
sudo chown ${USER}:docker /var/run/docker.sock. 
  link :"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socke

Answer (score 4):

Login to root user and run below commands.

```
useradd testuser
usermod -aG docker testuser
```

su - testuser (or open another terminal and login to testuser)

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

its works!

Comment: useradd does not create user folders. This is creating issues while running minikube; trying it on ubuntu:20.04

Answer (score 0):

Which User are you using now? Type on the terminal.

```
whoami
```

or

```
echo $USER
```

Then you can see your username. But This is not mandatory.

**Just Add the User to the Docker Group with below cmd**

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me by executing the line:

```
minikube start --force
```

Comment: minikube start --force