# Deploying a private ECR image written in Rust in Greengrass v2 failed

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, amazon-ecr, aws-iot-greengrass

I have been trying to deploy an image stored in a private ECR to Greengrass v2.

I keep getting the following error:

```
2022-07-07T19:54:22.811Z [ERROR] (pool-2-thread-47) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.activator.DeploymentActivator: merge-config. Deployment failed. {deploymentId=898e53f3-85b6-4850-b6cf-0f102a3cae96}
com.aws.greengrass.deployment.exceptions.ServiceUpdateException: Service service-name in broken state after deployment
        at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentConfigMerger.waitForServicesToStart(DeploymentConfigMerger.java:194)
        at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.activator.DefaultActivator.activate(DefaultActivator.java:84)
        at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentConfigMerger.updateActionForDeployment(DeploymentConfigMerger.java:150)
        at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentConfigMerger.lambda$mergeInNewConfig$0(DeploymentConfigMerger.java:102)
        at com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.UpdateSystemPolicyService.runUpdateActions(UpdateSystemPolicyService.java:95)
        at com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.UpdateSystemPolicyService.lambda$startup$0(UpdateSystemPolicyService.java:165)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

There are no other errors before or after it. I am trying to deploy it to a raspberry pi with Linux installed on it and I can run the image by running `docker run` on the server. Just not though Greengrass. The image is written in Rust.

Answer (score 0):

I was running the `sudo tail -f /greengrass/logs/greengrass.log` command and not `sudo tail -f /greengrass/logs/service-name.log` one. Once I did that I got more information. My error was `docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock:` so after a quick Google search I found a solution on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socke). ran `sudo usermod -a -G docker ggc_user` and deployed it again. Problem solved!