# Right way to build Docker images inside Jenkins container

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration

I've got Jenkins official image deployed into Docker container on my Mac and I need to use docker commands here.

**The question:** How to correctly embed Docker executables to Docker's image (i.e.Jenkins image) in  order Docker to use docker commands?

Here what I did:

1. Runned Jenkins container with additional parameter of `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`. Getting `permission denied` when try to access `docker build`.
2. Then I assigned sudo privileges inside container to Jenkins user `usermod -aG sudo jenkins` to Jenkins user and rebooted, the error is still here.

```
root@4328a7e643ea:/ groups jenkins
jenkins : jenkins sudo
```

3. Doing `chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock` on the host computer and reboot then hasn't helped too.

**Additional info:**

The parameters I used to create Jenkins container in Docker:

```
docker run --name jenkins --restart=on-failure --detach \
  --network jenkins --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 \
  --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 \
  --publish 9000:8080 --publish 60000:50000 \
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro \
  --volume /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker \
  --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  jenkins/jenkins:jdk17
```

After a whole day is wasted on reading & trying, I've finally gave up. Please, help me understand how to overcome this issue.

Comment: `usermod -aG sudo jenking` You only added to sudo group, not sudo privileges, that depends on the permissions. `permission denied when try to access docker build` Congrats on installing docker. Now, what is `stat /var/run/docker.sock` and result of `id` inside the container? `chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock on the host computer and reboot` Why did you _reboot_? So after reboot, permissions where reset. (?)

Comment: But you use DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 , not sock. Is there a hostname docker resolved by your DNS?

Comment: 1. The result of issuing "stat /var/run/docker.sock":
"16777232 30382117 lrwxr-xr-x 1 root daemon 0 35 "May 12 09:17:36 2023" "May 12 09:17:36 2023" "May 12 09:17:36 2023" "May 12 09:17:36 2023" 4096 0 0 /var/run/docker.sock".
2. The resilt of issuing "id" inside the container:
"uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)"

I rebooted to be sure that the changes applied. AFAIK the CHMOD changes is permanent.
If it's not, please corrent me.

Comment: I blindly copied it from a sample config.  I'm afraid not: tried to ping it on my host machine without result, neither I ran anything with the same name inside a Docker.

Answer (score 0):

I did some additional research and found [nice post](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-not-found-in-jenkins-pipeline/31683/23), where almost all possible solutions were mentioned. The similar group of posts resides [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socke).

So generally there is two options to actually run Docker's build job on Jenkins:

1. Embed Docker's binaries into Jenkins image. It could be just `docker-ce-cli` package.
2. Route Docker's binaries on the host to container VM:

```
docker run  \
  --name jenkins \
   --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \**
   --volume $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker \**
jenkins/jenkins
```

The first option routes **docker.sock** to container and the second exposes Docker's executable from a host to the container.

Unfortunately, the second option didn't worked for me under any circumstances: I tried to run container in the privilege mode, under the root user, added Jenkins user to root group (for my home Mac it's okay), `chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock`, `usermod -aG docker jenkins`. No way.

The last thing I gave a shot:

```
docker run -u root \
  --privileged \
  --name jenkins \
  --detach \
  --network jenkins \
  --publish 9000:8080 \
  --publish 60000:50000 \
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --volume $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker \
jenkins/jenkins
```

So finally I decided to give up and just embed Docker's executables (`docker-ce-cli`) into my Jenkins image with `--volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \` option, which successfully exposes all of my host-machine's images to the Jenkins's container.
Guess, it's more MacOS-related issues, because I red thousands messages of  Linux users, which has confirmed that routing of binaries (the 1-st way) works good for them.

So for now I'm building my image from this Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:jdk17
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
RUN install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
RUN chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
RUN echo \
  "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
  tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli docker-compose-plugin
```