# Permission Denied: Docker compose

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, permission-denied

/var/jenkins_home/workspace/faceapp_main@tmp/durable-7343158a/script.sh: 1: docker-compose: Permission denied

I'm using Jenkins to automate pipeline including build and push images to dockerhub using docker-compose. But I got this error ...

I realize one weird thing is that I can run docker, but not docker-compose in Jenkins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socke)

Comment: Are you running the dokcer image with root access?

Comment: you can try "chmod 777 /var/jenkins_home/workspace/*"

Comment: I actually tried the solutions above but it did not work. Btw I'm using Macos ...

Answer (score 0):

- if the permission denied because you can't access /var/run/docker.sock , you can try **sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock**
- if the permission denied because you need root privilege to run docker commands on your machine, you need to make the jenkins user have root privilege without the need to use sudo, you can try this

> $ sudo visudo
>
> ### Now add the below lines in your sudoers file :
>
> ```
> jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
> ```
>
> **then restart your jenkins service**
> $service jenkins restart

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. I realize one weird thing is that I can run docker, but not docker-compose in Jenkins(as I described)...